# Nativescript: Android app crashing in emulator switching tabs but nothing in console

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a nativescript iOS app and I just started trying out Android.  It loads up successfully but after switching tabs for a while in the TabView , the app just crashes but I see no indication of it in the terminal console.  The latest events I see are:

```
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.4.0)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativegridlayout), ElementNode(nativelabel))'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.4.0)} -> CreateElement(nativebutton)'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.4.0)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativegridlayout), ElementNode(nativebutton))'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.4.0)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativegridlayout), ElementNode(nativegridlayout))'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.4.0)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativepage), ElementNode(nativegridlayout))'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.4.0)} -> CreateElement(nativeimage)'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.4.0)} -> CreateElement(nativeimage)'
```

Is there any better way to get an indication of what the issue is while I am developing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - wrap the code in a try/catch block.  And, of course, run in a debugger where you pause on exceptions.